# Visual Studio 2005 Windows Forms Designer - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have a Windows Forms form that I am adding some new functionality to. The form has roughly 100 controls on it. I discovered when looking at the "properties" dropdown that there were several dozen controls in the form that served no purpose and were not visible on the form when they were selected in the properties window.

I couldn't find an easy solution to deleting these "invisible" controls by doing a search, so I decided to open the `.designer` file manually and carefully remove them from the code. This seemed to work fine until I had removed the last "unidentified" controls, and now I have the error stated above when opening the form in design view.

This project still compiles and runs fine, it is only in design view I am getting this error. Unfortunately, that makes updating this form in the future extremely difficult. Below is the complete error message.

> One or more errors encountered while loading the designer. The errors are listed below. Some errors can be fixed by rebuilding your project, while others may require code changes.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Hide
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchNormalEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, Boolean fastSearch)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.HandlesClauseManager.GetReferencedComponentType(String componentName, CodeTypeDeclaration codeTypeDecl, ITypeResolutionService loader, IDictionary& cache)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.HandlesClauseManager.ParseHandlesClauses(CodeTypeDeclaration codeTypeDecl, Boolean updateCache)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

Unfortunately, neither the error message nor opening the file in the Visual Studio 2005 designer indicates what line might be failing in the file - just this very ambiguous error message.

I would post the code that is causing the error here, but it takes up about 100,000 characters and the limit here is 30,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I backed up my designer code and then rolled back from [SourceSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe). Then I closed the design view of my form, closed Visual Studio, reopened Visual Studio, and pasted my designer code back in. After doing that, I could double-click my form to view it.

I am still not sure what caused the error, but doing the above fixed it. Weird.

Comment: Winforms designer is known to produce some unknown bugs randomly. Luckily, it doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been that you deleted some controls, but the UI left the event script including the Handles tag, which would cause this.  A handles tag with an invalid control name will cause the ignore and continue.  I just go through the code and try to find the handles that don't correspond to an existing control.